# Powershell - strip all whitespace from each line in hosts file before creating variables from IP, FQDN & Hostname & using these to ping

Tags: powershell, split, string-matching

Say we have a hosts file of:

```
10.10.10.10    test1.domain test1
20.20.20.201   test2.domain test2
30.30.301.30   test3.domain test3
40.40.40.40    test4.domain test4
```

Note the IPs with 3 digits in the host identifier, with this in mind, each line is structured slightly differently, in that those with the 2 digits, have more spaces between the IP and the FQDN.
Bearing in mind these differences, how would one either:
1. extract the FQDN from each line & ping as you go through each line
OR
2. strip out the IP altogether and then loop through each entry, pinging each FQDN as you go?

I can't seem to do option 1, and the closest to option 2 I have got is by doing this:

```
Get-Content hosts | ForEach-Object { $_Split()[3]; }
```

But this only prints out those hosts where there is 3 digits in the host identifier, whilst those with 2 digits have more whitespace between the IP and FQDN, therefore it counts the FQDN as being on the 4th field.

Can anyone assist with this please? I am fairly new to PowerShell coming from a UNIX background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings in Powershell are .Net String objects and thus contain powerful manipulation methods. [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) can be told to [omit empty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringsplitoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) elements. Like so,

```
# Read host list
$data = Get-Content C:\Temp\hostlist.txt
# Split each row from the file. Use space to split, omit empty elements
# Thus element 0 is the IP, 1 is the FQDN, 2 is the hostname
$data | ForEach-Object { ($_.split(" ", [StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries))[1] }

# Output
test1.domain
test2.domain
test3.domain
test4.domain
```